# How to dynamically set tab name in a formula?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a summary tab and multiple other tabs which are constructed the same way. I would like in my summary tab to gather information from all other tabs

Today, in the summary tab I have for each line:

- first cell: `My tab 1` -> name of a tab in the same spreadsheet
- second cell: `=COUNTIF('My tab 1'!$B7:$B; "OK")` -> count of all cells with "OK" text in column B.

I would like to use the tab name defined in the first cell inside the formula of the second cell. Is it possible and, if yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the INDIRECT function, described here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en

=INDIRECT($A$1)

In order to be seen as a reference for the range, INDIRECT needs the entire range reference as a single string, it seems. This gives you something like the answer to your question:

=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE($A$1, "!$B7:$B")), "OK")

What you give up there is that the $B7:$B portion of your address is now a string, so if you copy this cell down the page, the 7 won't get updated to 8, 9, and so on.

There may be other combinations of functions that will get you closer: this is the one I arrived at with a few minutes of searching.

Answer (score 1):

shorter solution:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT($A$1&"!B7:B"), "OK")
```

and for dragging it would be:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT($A$1&"!B"&ROW(B7)&":B"), "OK")
```