# How to concatenate TO_TEXT inside a VLookup function?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, formula, vlookup

If I wrote a formula in a cell:

```
=CONCATENATE("'",TO_TEXT(B2),"'")
```

I will get the 'B2_STRING'

Example: The B2 has a name, so I end up with 'Name'

But now I need this concatenation inside a VLookup function, so the function will know what sheet look for the info.

With this, everything works fine:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C2), 0, IF(C2="","",VLOOKUP(C2,'TABLE 1'!A2:C251,2,0)*G2))
```

But I want do this (and it returns me parse function error):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C2), 0, IF(C2="","",VLOOKUP(C2,CONCATENATE("'",TO_TEXT(B2),"'")!A2:C251,2,0)*G2))
```

I tried some other ways, but none worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically set tab name in a formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497534/how-to-dynamically-set-tab-name-in-a-formula)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `INDIRECT` for this. try:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C2), 0, IF(C2="",, VLOOKUP(C2, INDIRECT(B2&"!A2:C251"), 2, 0)*G2))
```